# Variable issues in if statements

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

I've just started python and I've decided to start with a simple program to parse a single line, two argument mathematical expression directly into an answer. Examples: 4 + 2, 3/4, 5435 * 3423, ect. To start with I'm trying to interpret the two variables in the equation before I work on having the program mathify them. My problem is the lines 39, 40, 42, and 43 are not modifying their respective variables at 1, 3, 2, and 5. In PyCharm, they are greyed out with an error about shadowing names out of scope.

It is currently almost 1AM and I'm not much of a night owl (I'll never make it as a coder lol) so it's probably a stupid mistake on my part but just in case...

```
primeNumber = None
secNumber = None
num11 = 0
buildList = []
finished = False

def interpret(statement):
    i = 0
    iMax = len(statement)
    while True:
        if i >= iMax:
            break
        parse(statement[i])
        i = i + 1

def parse(char, buildList=buildList):
    interrupt = [" ", "+", "-", "/", "*"]
    if char in interrupt:
        buildNumber(buildList)
        buildList.clear()
    elif num11 == 1:
        buildNumber(buildList)
        buildList.clear()
    else:
        buildList.append(char)

def isNumber(att):
    try:
        int(att)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def buildNumber(finishedList, num11 = num11):
    finishedNumber = ''.join(finishedList)
    print(finishedNumber)

    if num11 == 0:
        primeNumber = finishedNumber # <<< line 39
        num11 = 1
    elif num11 == 1:
        secNumber = finishedNumber
        finished = True
```

Comment: You should read about variable scope, local and global variables etc... The mistake is not so stupid and understanding what is going wrong requires a bit of thinking.

Comment: Can you post full program including calling your defined functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python variables that are referenced inside a function are assumed to be local if their value is set within the function.  To override this default behavior, and set globals from inside a function, you need to declare them with the `global` statement (only if you want to *write* them, you don't need to predeclare them to *read* them.)

Other issues with your code: you randomly mix accessing globals with passing around globals and defaulting to globals -- you should minimize your globals and treat them consistently; pick more descriptive variable names (why expect folks on SO to guess what `num11` means?); don't reinvent booleans (`num11` again); you initiate the construction of the second number prematurely.

I've reworked your code with the above issues in mind and added just enough wrapper and glue code to make it run:

```
firstNumber = None
secondNumber = None
finishedFirst = False
finishedSecond = False
operation = None

operations = {
    " ": None,
    "+": lambda a, b: a + b,
    "-": lambda a, b: a - b,
    "/": lambda a, b: a / b,
    "*": lambda a, b: a * b,
}

def interpret(statement):
    buildList = []

    for character in statement:
        parse(character, buildList)

    if not finishedSecond:
        buildNumber(buildList)

def parse(character, buildList):
    global operation

    if character in operations:
        if buildList:
            buildNumber(buildList)
            buildList.clear()
        if operations[character] is not None:
            operation = operations[character]
    else:
        buildList.append(character)

def buildNumber(finishedList):
    global firstNumber, secondNumber, finishedFirst, finishedSecond

    finishedNumber = ''.join(finishedList)

    if not finishedFirst:
        firstNumber = int(finishedNumber)
        finishedFirst = True
    else:
        secondNumber = int(finishedNumber)
        finishedSecond = True

statement = input("> ")

interpret(statement)

print(operation(firstNumber, secondNumber))
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
python3 test.py
> 34 + 56
90
```